# @pandas_udf - Linear regressions

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Can someone help me?

I need two groups to perform linear regression

example:

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'group_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                    'sex':['M','M','F','F','M','F','M','F','F','M'],
                    'x':[0,1,2,0,1,5,2,3,4,5],
                    'y':[2,1,0,0,0.5,2.5,3,4,5,6]})
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pdf)


result_schema =StructType([
  StructField('group_id',DoubleType()),
  StructField('sex',StringType()),
  StructField('x',DoubleType())
 ])

@pandas_udf(result_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)

def ols(df):
    group_id = df['group_id'].iloc[0]
    sex = df['sex'].iloc[0]
    y = df['y'].astype(int)
    X = df['x'].astype(int)
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
    
    
    return pd.DataFrame([[group_id] + [sex] + [model.params[1]]], columns=['group_id'] + ['sex'] + ['x'])


beta = df.groupby('group_id', 'sex').apply(ols)
beta.show()
```

return error:

> PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'IndexError:
> index out of bounds',

Comment: There is only 1 entry for some groups. How are you going to do a linear regression with 1 point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some groups with only one point, which makes it impossible to do a linear regression. To catch that in the function, you can add a check of number of rows in the dataframe, and return `null` in case there is only one row.

```
@pandas_udf(result_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def ols(df):
    group_id = df['group_id'].iloc[0]
    sex = df['sex'].iloc[0]

    if len(df) == 1:
        return pd.DataFrame([[group_id] + [sex] + [None]], columns=['group_id'] + ['sex'] + ['x'])

    else:        
        y = df['y'].astype(int)
        X = df['x'].astype(int)
        X = sm.add_constant(X)
        model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
        return pd.DataFrame([[group_id] + [sex] + [model.params[1]]], columns=['group_id'] + ['sex'] + ['x'])


df.groupby('group_id', 'sex').apply(ols).show()
+--------+---+-------------------+
|group_id|sex|                  x|
+--------+---+-------------------+
|     2.0|  M|               null|
|     3.0|  F|                1.0|
|     1.0|  M|-1.0000000000000002|
|     1.0|  F|               null|
|     2.0|  F|0.39999999999999986|
|     3.0|  M| 0.9999999999999998|
+--------+---+-------------------+
```

Comment: your answer is very good, but, in real case, i use a large dataset grouped by 2 arguments (like the example, group_id and sex). When i filter just a few "arguments" in sex and group_id, OK, however when i put all data set, i have the error: 'IndexError: index out of bounds'.  Even i grouping by one complete "argument", the error occurs. Can you help me again?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you were trying. Would you mind opening another question and provide the necessary details?

Comment: Thanks @mck, unfortunately I can't put the data, but i fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                    'sex':['M','M','F','F','M','F','M','F','F','M'],
                    'x':[0,1,2,0,1,5,2,3,4,5],
                    'y':[2,1,0,0,0.5,2.5,3,4,5,6]})
```

and simplistically looking at this group by

```
for name, sdf in df.groupby(['group_id', 'sex']):
    print(name)
    print(sdf)
```

we get

```
(1, 'F')
   group_id sex  x    y
2         1   F  2  0.0
(1, 'M')
   group_id sex  x    y
0         1   M  0  2.0
1         1   M  1  1.0
(2, 'F')
   group_id sex  x    y
3         2   F  0  0.0
5         2   F  5  2.5
(2, 'M')
   group_id sex  x    y
4         2   M  1  0.5
(3, 'F')
   group_id sex  x    y
7         3   F  3  4.0
8         3   F  4  5.0
(3, 'M')
   group_id sex  x    y
6         3   M  2  3.0
9         3   M  5  6.0
```

Now two points will get a linear (perfect) fit, and you need three to get some sort of deviation from a potentially perfect fit.  Some of these groups only have one data point that means you cannot fit the data...